# Find & replace code across all files in a folder in Linux

Tags: linux, editor, notepad++, sublimetext

I have been using Notepad++ for Windows when I want to find a certain text across all files in a given folder. This was extremely useful for debugging my MatLab code because one project entails tens of MatLab files.

I could also replace all texts into another across all files in a folder.
I could also replace things like `/r/n` which means line replacement.

Now I must need to work on a Linux server. Notepad++ couldn't be installed on the university server I am allotted to. And as far as I tried, Sublime Text couldn't find and replace things like `/r/n`

What option do I have on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text supports replacement of line breaks, but you have to select "regular expression" (Alt+R) and you have to enter the line break correctly (\n, not /r).

[image: Screenshot Sublime Text]

Answer (score 0):

The most useful method if find and replace. (Ctrl+H)

However, another possibility is the multiple selection as in the example number one of the official website: https://www.sublimetext.com/

How it works:

You select the word you want to replace, press Ctrl+D (which will select the same word with the same name). Continue pressing Ctrl+D until you selected every word you want to replace.

Once it is done, you will have a multiple selection, which means that every character will be write at each word selected position.

I invite you to check the example on their website, it is a very good illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kate, it is fine replacement for Notepad++.
Kate "Search and Replace" feature is very powerful.